# Leaftlet map displaying a white space

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet, pug

I am following a tutorial for a class and we are using leaflet maps, the code so far is very simple, a javascript app using a bootstrap template, node and pug. The teacher provided the steps, but, in my case the map just doesnt load and instead im greeted by a blank space.

I wanted to ask (given I followed the instructions) if it is possible i made a mistake or maybe a setting in my environment is what is causing the issue?

First I created the map script in js > maps.js

```
var map = L.map("main_map").setView([6.1630788, -75.631681], 17);

L.tileLayer("https://{​s}​.tile.openstreetmap.org/{​z}​/{​x}​/{​y}​.png", {​
attribution:
'&copy; <a href="https://wwww.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors',
}​).addTo(map);

L.marker([6.1573243, -75.6324465]).addTo(map);

L.marker([6.1573243, -75.6324485]).addTo(map);
```

On the layout I added the needed link and script  in the header, in the layout.pug file

```
doctype html
html
  head
  meta(charset='utf-8')
  meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no')
  meta(name='description' content='')
  meta(name='author' content='')
  title BiciRed - Portal Bici-amigo
  // Favicon
  link(rel='icon' type='image/x-icon' href='assets/favicon.ico')
  // Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)
  link(href='css/styles.css' rel='stylesheet')
  // THIS TWO LINES ARE THE ONES RELATED TO THE MAP
  link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css' integrity='sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A==' crossorigin='')
  script(src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js' integrity='sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA==' crossorigin='')
body
    block content
```

For the map to show I added the css code in the css > styles.css script that says this at the end.

```
#main_map 
{
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

So, thinking its all set for success, on my index.pug script I called the map inside a container like this:

```
 // Map
.container
  #main_map
```

But needless to say the result is a blank space where the map should be shown.
Any idea why this could happen?

this is  how its looking:
[image]

EDIT: I also referenced my map script on the bottom of my index.pug script. like this:

```
  // Core theme JS
  script(src='js/scripts.js')
  script(src='js/maps.js')
```

And also there is no error in the backlog that could help hint whats going on...

[image]

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Where do you reference your map.js script?

Comment: No error on console!

Comment: I referenced it on the bottom of my index.pug script, like this:

  script(src='js/maps.js')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very weird but after trying many things it actually started working, Im unsure what triggered the result but what I tried was:

1- I added the leaflet librarires to the project, instead of referencing them. This, on its own didnt solve the problem, but I thought it could be worth mentioning.

2- I re-pasted my maps.js code, I highly suuspect an indentation issue could be the core of the issues I was having, because the content was the same.

3- I tried running my code in different ways, after doing this third step the map started showing, so Im a bit unsure if it could be related to the end result but again, could be worth mentioning.